# How to apply a cumulative patch on JBoss EAP 7 with other patches installed?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, bean-validation, wildfly-10, jboss-eap-7

I have a JBoss EAP 7 instance that has already been patched to 7.0.7 with jboss-cli.

I also patched it with the [Hibernate Validator 6.0.2 Wildfly patch](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator-modules/6.0.2.Final/hibernate-validator-modules-6.0.2.Final-wildfly-10.1.0.Final-patch.zip) to be able to use JSR 380 - Bean Validation 2.0 (as explained in [Hibernate Validator documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_updating_hibernate_validator_in_wildfly)).

Now I want to apply the latest JBoss EAP 7.0.8 patch, but I'm receiving this message as a feedback from jboss-cli:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot apply cumulative patch if there are other patches applied [layer-base-wildfly-10.1.0.Final-hibernate-validor-6.0.2.Final, layer-base-wildfly-10.1.0.Final-hibernate-validor-6.0.1.Final]`

What would be the best way to apply the 7.0.8 cumulative patch? Should I:

1. rollback hibernate validator patch,
2. apply 7.0.8 patch,
3. apply hibernate validator patch again?

Or is there a more straightforward approach?

Comment: JBoss 7 EAP and WildFly 10 are different beasts. I'm not entirely clear on what is done where from your question. The title claims JBoss 7 EAP, the text shows a WildFly 10 error message.

Comment: JBoss EAP 7 is based on Wildfly 10, thus the patches are compatible. The error message only states the name of the patch. My question is clearly stated in the title: how to apply a cumulative patch on JBoss EAP 7 with other patches installed? Regardless of the nature of the other patches.

Comment: you have to follow your solution in 3 steps, all the more so as the hibernate patch is not an official one

Comment: @ehsavoie Not official as in not built specially by RedHat for EAP, you mean?

Comment: Yes. Also please note that isf EAP is based on WildFly source code, they are not strictly identical (all the more so after patching).